# Using phalcon, I have two databases, How can I select a database before $builder with modelsManager?

Tags: model, phalcon

Before this $builder, I want to set a database, what shall I do? thanks in advance!

```
$builder = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
->columns($cols)
->distinct(true)
->from($ZUC)
->leftJoin($ZU, "$ZU.user_id = $ZUC.user_id")
->leftJoin($ZSC, "$ZUC.subclass_id = $ZSC.subclass_id")
->leftJoin($ZC, "$ZC.class_id = $ZSC.class_id")
->leftJoin($ZCH, "$ZCH.order_no = $ZUC.order_no")
->where($conStr, $conArr)
->orderBy($order)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Share with you。Like this

```
  $zx_user_class = new ZxUserClass(); //your primary table
  $zx_user_class->setConnectionService('dbWrite'); // select databse
  $modelsManager = $zx_user_class->getModelsManager();
  $builder = $modelsManager->createBuilder()
   ->columns($cols)
   ->distinct(true)
   ->from($ZUC)
   ->leftJoin($ZU, "$ZU.user_id = $ZUC.user_id")
   ->leftJoin($ZSC, "$ZUC.subclass_id = $ZSC.subclass_id")
   ->leftJoin($ZC, "$ZC.class_id = $ZSC.class_id")
   ->leftJoin($ZCH, "$ZCH.order_no = $ZUC.order_no")
   ->where($conStr, $conArr)
   ->orderBy($order)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change db service in di or use setReadConnectionService method in model(though not sure about this last one).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setSchema() method to define that, Here the reference;
[Link](https://olddocs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.1/reference/models-advanced.html#pointing-to-a-different-schema)

Comment: Thanks!Using schema,did I have to set two databases in one server?